# sharepoint 2010:cannot connect the config database

Tags: sharepoint

I got some problems of sharepoint 2010, here is the detail:
at first i setup sharepoint 2010 server,and the config database is hosted in a win server 2008 r2 of which ip is 192.168.10.102, but later, for some reason, i changed that ip into 192.168.10.104, and of course, problem occurs:when i open the sharepoint administrator center,it shows me "cannot connect to the config database".
how can i fix this problem? i mean,where can i change the connection string of the config database? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection string for SharePoint 2010 configuration database is located in the Windows Registry, the key is called `dsn` and it is located at:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDb
```